# How to export strings as pure ASCII?

Tags: programming, export, string-manipulation, conversion, character-encoding

The [`"PrintableASCII"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RawCharacterEncodings.html#27200) characters set consists of 97 characters, including space ([`\[RawSpace]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/RawSpace.html)) and two control characters: the newline character `\n` ([`\[NewLine]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/NewLine.html)) and the carriage return `\r` ([`\[RawReturn]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/RawReturn.html)), which are the only allowed `WhitespaceCharacter`s in this encoding (highlighted by light blue in the following table):

```
printableASCIISet = 
  Cases[ToCharacterCode[FromCharacterCode[Range[0, 255]], "PrintableASCII"], k_Integer];

printableASCIISet // Length

Grid[
  Flatten[
   Transpose /@
    Partition[{#, FromCharacterCode[#]} & /@ printableASCIISet, UpTo@20], 1],
  Frame -> {All, {{True, False}}}, Spacings -> 0.2, FrameStyle -> LightGray] /.
 s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, WhitespaceCharacter] :>
  Item[StringTrim[ToString[InputForm@s], "\""], Background -> LightBlue]
```

> ```
> 97
> ```
>
> [image: output]

The [`"ASCII"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RawCharacterEncodings.html#27200) encoding allows all [control characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CharacterCodes.html#29993) and consists of the characters with codes from 0 to 127.

**I wish to allow only newlines (`\n`), carriage returns (`\r`), spaces () and tabs (`\t`) as whitespace characters when exporting as ASCII.** So the only difference with `"PrintableASCII"` is that tabs are also allowed, and of course all the special, [extended-ASCII and Unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198513/590388) must be converted into their corresponding `FullForm`s.

Here are example strings with expected output in the exported textual file:

1. Input:

   ```
   ExportAsASCII["test1.txt", "Here is a string in quotes:\n\"quoted string\""]
   ```

   Verbatim contents of the created file "test1.txt":

   `Here is a string in quotes:
   "quoted string"`

   (note the absence of the outer quotation marks and also that the inner quotes aren't escaped).
2. Input:

   ```
   ExportAsASCII["test2.txt", "Lamé \[LongRightArrow] αβ+"]
   ```

   Verbatim contents of the created file "test2.txt":

   `Lam\[EAcute] \[LongRightArrow] \[Alpha]\[Beta]+`

   (note the `é` encoded as `\[EAcute]`, not as `\\[EAcute]`).
3. Input:

   ```
   s = "\!\(\r\n\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-Pi\), \(Pi\)]\(g[\r\n\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \r\n\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)] + \r\n\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(6\)]] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)"

   ExportAsASCII["test3.txt", s]
   ```

   Verbatim contents of the created file "test3.txt":

   `\!\(
   \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-Pi\), \(Pi\)]\(g[
   \*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + 
   \*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)] + 
   \*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(6\)]] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)`

   (note that the newline characters aren't escaped and present here as actual new lines).

**How is it possible to implement `ExportAsASCII`?**

---

P.S. Actually the above-described behavior is (by the essence) what I expected for `Export`ing as [`"String"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/String.html) with [`CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RawCharacterEncodings.html#27200) according to the Documentation:

```
Export["test.txt", "Lamé \[LongRightArrow] αβ+", "String", CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"]
```

But currently `"ASCII"` as well as `"PrintableASCII"` and [`None`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RawCharacterEncodings.html#30648) seem to be simply ignored by `Export`. :(

Comment: Any feedback from WRI about this and related issues?

Comment: @Kuba I have not yet written to the support, still trying to figure it out on my own.

Comment: @Kuba The Support responded: "There seems to be a disregard for certain characters when Exporting with ASCII as the CharacterEncoding, regardless of their character codes." As a workaround is proposed manual conversion of such characters into their full forms using helper function `fullname[c_String]:=StringReplace[ToString[c,InputForm,CharacterEncoding->"ASCII"],"\"\\["~~a__~~"]\"":>"\\["~~a~~"]"]`.

Comment: You are misreading the documentation if you think "String" would be appropriate for this.  "String" is a binary format, which by design ignores CharacterEncoding, and converts characters 0-255 to the corresponding byte values (and other characters into long names).

Comment: @ItaiSeggev This comment serves as a proper answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146294/280) question. Note that some Unicode characters aren't converted into long names, for example `\[CirclePlus]`. Should it be counted as a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### `ExportAsASCII`

Currently I know only one [well-documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialCharacters-StringsAndCharacters.html#1943280499) and *working* (with exception for the NULL character `\.00` and a [few characters from Unicode Private Use Area](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154595/280) which normally shouldn't appear in code) method to convert all special and non-ASCII characters in an arbitrary string into `"PrintableASCII"` programmatically:

```
toInputForm[s_String] := StringTake[
   ToString[s, InputForm, CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"], {2, -2}];
```

In general this method duplicates every backslash which is a part of a special character like `\n`, [`\!`, `\*` etc.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html):

```
toInputForm["\!\n"]
```

> ```
> "\\!\\n"
> ```

... and adds *two* backslashes before every *escaping* backslash:

```
toInputForm["\\"]
toInputForm["\""]
toInputForm["\\n"]
```

> ```
> "\\\\"
> ```

> ```
> "\\\""
> ```

> ```
> "\\\\n"
> ```

AFAIK the only two characters which have to be escaped inside of the *Mathematica* strings are backslash `\` (the escaping character and the integral part of every special character) and double quote `"` (which indicates the start and the end of the string). This is important since for performing the reverse transformation we have to care about every such character.

Based on these considerations we can write a list of replacement rules which will perform the reverse transformation according to our goals:

```
unescape[s_String] := 
  StringReplace[
   s, {"\\\\" -> "\\", "\\\"" -> "\"", "\\n" -> "\n", "\\r" -> "\r", "\\t" -> "\t"}];
```

Now we can implement `ExportAsASCII` as follows:

```
ExportAsASCII[fileName_String, s_String] := 
 Export[fileName, unescape[toInputForm[s]], "String"]
```

... or perhaps more efficiently using `WriteString`:

```
ExportAsASCII[fileName_String, s_String] :=
  Module[{str = OpenWrite[fileName, BinaryFormat -> True]},
   WriteString[str, unescape[toInputForm[s]]]; Close[str]];
```

... or `BinaryWrite`:

```
ExportAsASCII[fileName_String, s_String] :=
  Close[BinaryWrite[fileName, unescape[toInputForm[s]]]];
```

This implementation passes all the tests given in the question. Note however that this implementation has the same defect as `Export[..., "String"]` for Unicode characters: in the exported file escaped and unescaped versions of the same non-`PrintableASCII` character can't be distinguished. For example, both from `"\!"` and `"\\!"` `Export` produces a file containing `\!`. There is no way to avoid such inconsistency entirely since if we will write `\!` from `"\!"` and `\\!` from `"\\!"`, we still have ambiguity for `"\\!"` and `"\\\!"` which both will be written as `\\!`. That's because we must write `"\\"` as single backslash `\` it actually represents.

---

### `ImportAsASCII`

Since non-`PrintableASCII` characters are presented in `FullForm` in the exported file, they will be imported already escaped like `"\\[Paragraph]"`, `"\\200"` or `"\\!"`. We must avoid escaping them again when we replace `"\\"` with `"\\\\"` (the reverse of what `unescape` does). Let us find all characters which may appear after `\` in `FullForm` of a non-`PrintableASCII` character (excluding `\t` which I include in my character set):

```
mySet = Join[ToCharacterCode["\t"], 
   Cases[ToCharacterCode[FromCharacterCode[Range[0, 255]], "PrintableASCII"], k_Integer]];
disallowed = Complement[Range[0, 65535], mySet];
chs = toInputForm[FromCharacterCode[#]] & /@ disallowed;
sel = Select[chs, StringTake[#, 1] === "\\" &];
DeleteDuplicates[StringTake[#, {2}] & /@ sel]
```

> ```
> {"0", "b", "f", "[", "1", "2", ":", ")", "!", "@", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", "_", "+", "/", "`"}
> ```

The named characters (like `\[Mod2Key]`) and input forms [`\:xxxx`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154563/280) (where `xxxx` is hexadecimal code) and `\xxx` (where `xxx` contains only decimals) can be matched by `"\\" ~~ RegularExpression["\\[[A-z12]+\\]|:[a-f\\d]{4}|\\d{3}"]` (note that this regex is exhaustive but still excessive, and will match also invalid inputs like `\[foo]` or `\999`). There also is [partially](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102381/280) allowed input form [`\.xx`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CharacterCodes.html#24176) which normally isn't generated by `toInputForm`, so I do not account for it.

Hence a regular expression matching `"\\"` which will protect such characters may be written as

```
temperedBackslash = 
  RegularExpression["\\\\(?![bf()!@%^&*_+`/]|\\[[A-z12]+\\]|:[a-f\\d]{4}|\\d{3})"];
```

Here is a function which performs the reverse operation:

```
escape[s_String] := 
  StringReplace[s, {temperedBackslash -> "\\\\", "\"" -> "\\\"", 
                    "\n" -> "\\n", "\r" -> "\\r", "\t" -> "\\t"}];

ImportAsASCII[fileName_String] :=
 ToExpression["\"" <> escape[FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList[fileName]]] <> "\"", 
  InputForm]
```

Consistency check:

```
string = "\!\(\r\n\*Lamé \[LongRightArrow] αβ+\\\\\\\\\)⊕\[Wolf]\[RuleDelayed]\"";
string === ImportAsASCII[ExportAsASCII["test1.txt", string]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Games like this are dangerous.  Consider the string `s="\"\\\"\\n\\\"\""`.  It will not export correctly (it produces a file containing `"\"\n\""`), and on import will generated an invalid syntax error.  Which isn't to say your function is not useful in practice.  
I don't think there is a built-in function which does this, in part because you are wanting to have it both ways: some special characters are themselves, others are not.  How is the function supposed to know which is which? (Also, there are special rules for interpretting the contents insde `\!\(...\)` which are being ignored.)

Comment: @ItaiSeggev Thank you for this example. With your string `Export` (as `"String"`) behaves exactly as `ExportAsASCII`. In some other cases this introduces inconsistency since, for example, both from `"\!"` and `"\\!"` `Export` produces a file containing `\!`. I do not know whether this is intended behavior or a bug. Obviously it isn't appropriate for `ExportAsASCII` but I still can't figure out how to avoid such inconsistency. I've improved `ImportAsASCII`: now it works correctly with your example.