# How to create new custom symbols like \[Wolf]?

Tags: front-end, customization, symbols

In Mathematica, we can often get very special symbols by typing `esc ... esc` or `\[...]`, such as the Wolf or Mathematica's logo. Is it possible to define new special symbols like those and then use them as `\[Wolf]`?

Comment: see [InputAliases](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputAliases.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by a "special symbol".

If you just want an <kbd>Esc</kbd> ... <kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut to insert some predetermined expression, you can use an [input alias](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases.html).

Any Unicode character in the [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) can be entered by typing `\:xxxx`, where `xxxx` is its code point in hexadecimal.  You can of course define a more memorable input alias for it.

If you really want something that behaves like a character but has a custom glyph, then the answer is "not really".  You would have to find an unused code point in the Private Use Area and edit Mathematica's font files to add a glyph for that code point.  Which means these notebooks would only display correctly on your machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to create a brand new character, but I think I'll give up

Comment: I'm alright with this; I'm not quite ready to see emojis in a Mathematica notebook just yet...

Comment: @Itai May I ask you what encoding is used by the input form `\xxx`? For example, `"\041"` corresponds to the character `"!"` with code 33.

Comment: @Itai Also please take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154595/280) .